# Strange behaviour when having a group in vbox

Tags: javafx

Can someone please explain me why this strange behaviour exists? When I have a group in a vbox every item in a child appears to modify the siblings to.

Following strange behaviour happens:

**everything normal here**

[image: everything normal here]

**here too everything normal**

[image: here too everything normal]

**whoops, why did the searchbar move???**

[image: whoops, why did the searchbar move???]

First of the structure of the application I have:

```
root (VBox) //vbox so the menubar has its own space
├───menubar (MenuBar)
└───contentroot (Group)
    ├───searchbar (TextField) //searchbar should always be on the top left
    └───nodeRoot (Group)
        ├───circle1 (Nodes)
        └───circle2 (Nodes)
```

The root is a vbox so the menubar has its own unchallenged space. The searchbar should always be top left, directly under the menubar.
The nodeRoot should contain every other node. Kinda like a drawing board which I should be able to drag around.

Code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    VBox root = new VBox();

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(new Menu("File"));
    Group contentRoot = new Group();
    contentRoot.getChildren().add(new TextField("SearchBar"));
    Group nodeRoot = new Group();
    contentRoot.getChildren().add(nodeRoot);

    root.getChildren().addAll(menuBar, contentRoot);

    Circle circle = new Circle(30, Color.RED);
    nodeRoot.getChildren().add(circle);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        circle.setTranslateX(event.getSceneX() - 15);
        circle.setTranslateY(event.getSceneY() - 15);
    });
}
```

**My guess why this happens:**
The problem started to appear after I added the menubar and put everything into a VBox. This is when the siblings of the nodeRoot get changed too. My guess is that because VBox is a Region the behaviour is different than a normal group which expands. But then I dont understand why it only happens if the item moves to the left or top.

**Can somebody please explain why this happens and how I can fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [javadocs for `Group`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html):

> A Group will take on the collective bounds of its children and is not
>   directly resizable.

When you click near the top or left of the scene, the circle's bounds include negative values. Since the group takes on those bounds, it also takes on negative values. The `TextField` never has any layout bounds set, so the `Group` positions it at `(0,0)`. Hence the text field can end up below or to the right of the circle. The vbox positions the group in order to try and contain it entirely, so it shifts it right if it contains negative x-value bounds and down if it contains negative y-value bounds.

If you use a `Pane` to contain the circle, instead of a `Group`:

```
Pane contentRoot = new Pane();
```

it behaves more intuitively: the `Pane` does not take on the union of the bounds of its child nodes, so if the circle has negative bounds, it just moves left and/or above the pane's visible area.

Comment: The problem with the nodeRoot is that I also made it moveable so I have "infinite" space to place my nodes. When using a Pane instead a group for the nodeRoot the nodes tend to clip when moving out of the pane. That is why Im using a group. Or do you know any other solution?

Comment: If you want it not to clip when it moves to the left, then I guess the question is, how else would you expect it to behave? If the circle has negative coordinates and you want it to remain visible, then surely the text field has to move to the right to accommodate it.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. The clipping was meant not for the window but when moving the nodeRoot (in this case the group, in your suggestion the pane). This is because the pane is not infinitely big and has some bounds.
If I for example move the pane 300px right, the nodes in the pane clip not at the window-borders but at the left side of the pane which is now 300px in.

Comment: I must apologize, I always used the pane on the nodeRoot level not on the contentRoot level. At the contentRoot level no clipping is happening. :) A little more careful reading helps sometimes alot

Comment: No problem... glad the answer helped.